# How can I use .psd file as icon in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I use flutter_launcher_icons for png file but when I use .psd instead of .png it is not working. Is there any way for use .psg file as launcher icon?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/psd_sdk/example
this package enables to read psd files

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [image package](https://pub.dev/packages/image) here you can read .psd files.